# Unable To Play Minecraft Multiplayer On Any Server

Tags: networking, server, java, dns, minecraft

Hello Guys I am Adi a New Ubuntu user currently using the latest version of Ubuntu 20.04LTS
I was Playing Minecraft good till yesterday From today I am Unable to play on any minecraft server Its too laggy, My Internet is fine and my ping on speedtest.net is 3ms I am using java-8 as the minecraft guide shows, I litreally did everything clearing cache, restarting, reinstall launcher, reinstalling minecraft, changing dns, reinstalling java, enabled - disable  firewall  but did't happen its the same problem please help me I am a Streamer and Can't Stream PLEASE HELP GUYS

Comment: "*Unable to play*" does not explain the problem that you are experiencing with enough detail for us help you diagnose the problem.

Comment: OK please Clarify {unable to play} does not provide useful info.

Answer (score 0):

Try running:

```
sudo ufw allow 25565
```

and then try rejoining the server.